# strange but true historical haiku

Tags: riddle, poetry, history

> Kingdom without king 
> while surrounded by itself 
> was declaring war,
>
> not demanding land. 
> Led by a fleet admiral, 
> without a navy.
>
> But it had demands, 
> from many other countries: 
> from its own allies.

When did this happen?

Comment: Why did you change the riddle after it was solved? In general we want puzzles to stay in the same state they were at time of solving.

Comment: @bobble : if you think the slight aesthetic change really changed anything in the puzzle's meaning, please tell me and I'll gladly revert it.

Comment: The difference is tiny - "without wanting" means no _desire_ for land, while "not demanding" means not _asking_ for land. A small change, true, but it is indeed a change years after solving.

Comment: @bobble besides the aesthetic change I thought it is even more accurate and reflects reality better. It is even suited to the answer better. The main catch in that line is, that when countries go to war, they usually have territorial demands. But in this case the country didn't have any territorial demands from those it declared war on, but did have territorial demands from its allies (yeah, history is complicated). And now that I think of, the earlier formulation was flat out wrong: they *did* desire land, but not from the declaration. Now it's more clear that they didn't have demands in it.

Comment: You can leave it as-is if you want. I simply commented because I noticed that this was a necro-edit of an already-solved riddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's

> Hungary during WWII

Explanation:

> After WWI, Hungary [remained formally a kingdom](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magyar_Kir%C3%A1lys%C3%A1g#1920%E2%80%931946), but the Habsburgs were not allowed in the country and Hungary has been ruled by the regent [Miklós Horthy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikl%C3%B3s_Horthy) - de facto a dictator, former Austro-Hungarian navy admiral. But Hungary remained landlocked after [Croatia split off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Croatia-Slavonia), indeed, all the land around Hungary post-WWI (now other countries) belonged to it before (with the exception of [General Government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Government)).

> During WWII, Hungary was allied to Germany, as well as Slovakia, Croatia and Romania. Hungary. however, kept territorial demands to all these countries (this included e.g. [a short war with Slovakia](https://www.valka.cz/newdesign/v900/clanek_12030.html)). There were also some territorial demands towards Germany ([Burgenland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgenland)), but these were not expressed too loudly...

Comment: Since this is an answer based on history, would you mind posting a link so we know you didn't just make it up? :)

Comment: A few details are wrong (it was Miklós, not István, and Burgenland belongs to Austria not Germany), and the question is not directly answered (against whom was the war declared and when), but otherwise it's correct.

Comment: @vsz Thanks, I fixed Horthy (and also added links). However, Burgenland at the time *did* belong to Germany...

Comment: The question itself was technically still not answered, but as the puzzle has obviously been solved, I accept it and provide the missing info: it happened in December 1941, when Hungary declared war on the USA, being required to follow the Germans. They obviously had no land claims against the USA. They had, however, land claims against several of their allies. Why were they still allies? The Germans have actually split the contested lands in two (see Vienna Award), forcing the countries into a bitter alliance. If one wouldn't behave as the Germans wanted, both halves would go to the other one

Answer (score 2):

Could this be a reference to

> Brexit?

*Kingdom without king*

> The United Kingdom has a queen, not a king.

*while surrounded by itself*

> It's surrounded by British waters, with no land neighbours except in Ireland.

*was declaring war,*

> Well, not exactly, but you wouldn't be the first person to compare recent Britain-EU relations to a war.

*without wanting land.*

> Britain isn't trying to claim land from the EU.

*Led by a fleet admiral,*
*without a navy.*

> Maybe this refers to Britain's honorary Fleet Admirals like Prince Charles and Prince Philip?

*But it had demands,*

> Oh yes. Lots of 'em.

*from many other countries:*

> The remaining EU member states.

*from its own allies.*

> Many of whom are allies of Britain, e.g. via NATO.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I didn't insert any of my own political opinion here! :-)

Answer (score 1):

When did this happen? I'll tell you exactly when:

> 1918 - 1922, the Russian Civil War.

Explanation:

> Kingdom without king 
>   while surrounded by itself 
>   was declaring war,

...

> Tsar Nicholas II had been executed (1918 Jly 17), along with the rest of the royal family, so there was no King on the throne. Surrounded by itself? I guess that's a poetic way of saying Civil War. Declaring war? Yes, definitely, making war is as good as declaring war, and a Civil War is definitely war.

...

> without wanting land. 
>   Led by a fleet admiral, 
>   without a navy.

...

> It's tough to make this first part fit, cuz one of the Bolshevik slogans was "peace, bread, and land". However, that was referring to giving land to the peasants from the kulaks, not an external war of conquest for land. "led by a fleet admiral without a navy". That would be Admiral Kolchak, who led the White **Army**. The Russian Navy, as far as I know, did not partake in the Civil War at all. (Cruiser Aurora fired some shots on the Winter Palace, but that was at the start of the Bolshevik Revolution (1917 Nov 07), whereas the Civil War didn't start till sometime in 1918 and was entirely taking place in the towns and countryside.)

...

> But it had demands, 
>   from many other countries: 
>   from its own allies.

...

> Indeed, Lenin's goal was not only to win the Civil War but to "export the revolution", meaning that other countries should start their own communist revolution, with civil war if necessary. He tried to incite this with powerful rhetoric. His demand of other countries was to throw off capitalism, and in general, "all workers of the world, unite!". I know it's a little confusing with the "without wanting land" part, since this seems want a world unification under one banner. But it's more like wanting all the workers of the world to take control of their workplaces, and getting rid of nationalism (which is how the world was before Napoleon), so not necessarily uniting the world under one govt.

...

> "from its own allies". Well in WW1, Russia was allied with Britain, France, then America...some other countries too. Then in the Civil War, all that changed. I believe both the Reds and the Whites made demands of these "allies", to convert to communism and to aid the anti-communist movement respectively, so it is true no matter which side you look at it.